# Which one is the main process of node-webkit app?

Tags: node.js, node-webkit

I wrote a node-webkit app which doesn't create subprocess. Then I run `ps`, but found three node-webkit processes. I want to know which one is my app, and what are the other two processes doing? I'm using OSX 10.10.

```
$ ps aux | grep fbt                                                                                                            
laike9m         11622 111.1  1.6  3766608 272416   ??  R    10:37上午   0:09.52 /Applications/fbtmac.app/Contents/Frameworks/node-webkit Helper.app/Contents/MacOS/node-webkit Helper --type=renderer --no-sandbox --lang=zh-CN --enable-threaded-compositing --nodejs --working-directory=/Applications/fbtmac.app/Contents/Resources/app.nw --node-main=index.js --child-clean-exit --enable-threaded-compositing --disable-accelerated-video-decode --enable-software-compositing --channel=11619.1.128080293  
laike9m         11621   4.2  0.5  2800664  90112   ??  S    10:37上午   0:00.97 /Applications/fbtmac.app/Contents/Frameworks/node-webkit Helper.app/Contents/MacOS/node-webkit Helper --type=gpu-process --channel=11619.0.1688422656 --no-sandbox --supports-dual-gpus=false --gpu-driver-bug-workarounds=10,17,21,23,26,36,42 --disable-accelerated-video-decode --gpu-vendor-id=0x8086 --gpu-device-id=0x0d26 --gpu-driver-vendor --gpu-driver-version
laike9m         11619   3.3  0.2  3023464  40944   ??  U    10:37上午   0:01.62 /Applications/fbtmac.app/Contents/MacOS/node-webkit
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NW inherits Chromium's multiprocess architecture: https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/multi-process-architecture

Node.js runs in the same thread as the DOM (web engine) in the renderer process

Comment: Thx. Could you point out which one is my app's process? I mean the "renderer process" you mentioned.

Comment: So the `--type=renderer` process is the one I'm looking for?